# Golang: optimal way of typing associative slices?

Tags: go

I'm parsing loads of HTTP logs pursing a goal tell how many requests each IP address generated.

The first thing I did is:

```
var hits = make(map[string]uint)

// so I could populate it with
hits[ipAddr]++
```

However, I would like to make it "typed", so that it would be immediately clear that `hits[string]uint` uses an IP address as a string identifier. I thought, well maybe a struct can help me:

```
type Hit struct {
    IP    string
    Count uint
}
```

But that way (I think) I'm loosing the performance, because now I how to really look for specific Hit to increment it's count. I tolerate that I could be paranoid here, and could simple go for the loop:

```
var hits = make([]Hit)

// TrackHit just damn tracks it
func TrackHit(ip string) {
    for hit, _ := range hits {
        if hit.IP == ip {
             hit.Count++
             return
        }
    }

    append(hits, Hit{
        IP:    ip,
        Count: 0,
    })
}
```

But that just looks ... suboptimal. I think everything that could be written in 1 line makes you shine as professional, and when 1 line turns into 13, I tend to feel "whaaa? Doing something wrong here, mom?"

Any typed one-liners here in Go?

Thanks

Comment: type IP string; type Hits map[IP]uint

Comment: and then `hits[IP{ipAddr}]++`? And if yes, does it allocate twice as much memory, because we create new IP each string we loop through?

Comment: hits[IP("127.0.0.1")]++; It's more or less idiomatic way.

Comment: Any ideas why it's being down-voted?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, don't take it personally if people downvote without telling you why ;-)

Comment: @nothingmuch thanks for the support. Yeah, it just feels like you stand there with banner "help" and they go and spit on you passing by.  Just because they didn't like what was on there.

Comment: Haters gonna hate... I personally don't think your question is lazy or somehow invalid. Arbitrary key types are mentioned in passing in the tour of go, and though defining type aliases is a common technique in go, it's not immediately obvious how these concepts connect.

Comment: `I think everything that could be written in 1 line makes you shine as professional`, not sure where you're coming from with that, but the Go community favors clarity over conciseness whenever possible. Saving newline characters doesn't somehow make your code better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Uvelichitel pointed out, you can use a typed string:

```
type IP string
var hits = make(map[IP]uint)
hits[IP("127.0.0.1")]++
```

Or you could use the existing stdlib IP type:

```
var hits = make(map[net.IP]uint)
hits[net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")]++
```

Either would make it clear that you're referring to IPs, without the overhead introduced by looping over a slice of structs for every increment. The latter has the advantage of giving you full stdlib support for any other IP manipulation you need to do, and a more compact representation (4 bytes for IPv4 addresses instead of a 7-15 character UTF-8 string), at the cost of parsing the strings. Which one is better will depend on your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer, @Adrian. How would I go about making another grouping level? Say, first I'd want to group by request date, then by request IP? Would `hits[Date("2017/May/1")][net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")]++` work? Would I be able to use it without explicitly checking if `hits[Date("2017/May/1")]` exist first?

Comment: Or should I define `type RequestGroup struct { Date string, IP net.IP }` and then `hits = make(map[ReqeustGroup]uint)`?